# linking errors while building qt3d with msvc 2013 (qt5.4)

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt3d, qt5.4

I'm trying to build qt3d libraries in QtCreator with msvc2013. I'm following the [qt3d installation steps](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt3D-Installation), but I'm getting linking error:

```
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -FS -O2 -MD -Zc:strictStrings -EHsc -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_3D_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_EGL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I"..\..\include" -I"..\..\include\Qt3D" -I"..\..\include\Qt3D\5.3.0" -I"..\..\include\Qt3D\5.3.0\Qt3D" -I"tmp" -I"..\private" -I"global" -I"painting" -I"arrays" -I"effects" -I"materials" -I"geometry" -I"viewing" -I"math3d" -I"scene" -I"scene_ai" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\code" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\code\BoostWorkaround" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\include" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\include\Compiler" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\ConvertUTF" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\zlib" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\irrXML" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\unzip" -I"scene_bezier" -I"network" -I"graphicsview" -I"textures" -I"surfaces" -I"api" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtCore\5.4.0" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtCore\5.4.0\QtCore" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtGui\5.4.0" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtGui\5.4.0\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtOpenGL" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtANGLE" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtCore" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtNetwork" -I".moc\release" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013" -Fo.obj\release\ @C:\Users\eDS\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_qgltexture2d_p.obj.696.166609.jom
moc_qgltexture2d_p.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /VERSION:5.30 /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\..\lib\Qt53D.dll @C:\Users\eDS\AppData\Local\Temp\Qt53D.dll.696.168263.jom
   Creating library ..\..\lib\Qt53D.lib and object ..\..\lib\Qt53D.exp
qglpainter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor4f@16 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QGLPainter::updateFixedFunction(class QFlags<enum QGLPainter::Update>)" (?updateFixedFunction@QGLPainter@@QAEXV?$QFlags@W4Update@QGLPainter@@@@@Z)
qglpainter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColorPointer@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl qt_gl_setVertexAttribute(enum QGL::VertexAttribute,class QGLAttributeValue const &)" (?qt_gl_setVertexAttribute@@YAXW4VertexAttribute@QGL@@ABVQGLAttributeValue@@@Z)
qglpainter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLightModelfv@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QGLPainter::updateFixedFunction(class QFlags<enum QGLPainter::Update>)" (?updateFixedFunction@QGLPainter@@QAEXV?$QFlags@W4Update@QGLPainter@@@@@Z)
qglpainter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLightfv@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl setLight(int,class QGLLightParameters const *,class QMatrix4x4 const &)" (?setLight@@YAXHPBVQGLLightParameters@@ABVQMatrix4x4@@@Z)
qglpainter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QGLPainter::updateFixedFunction(class QFlags<enum QGLPainter::Update>)" (?updateFixedFunction@QGLPainter@@QAEXV?$QFlags@W4Update@QGLPainter@@@@@Z)
....
....//continues
```

please any ideas?

Comment: You don't have OpenGL libraries available, or you do but not in your linker setup. glLoadIndentity() etc are pretty basic OpenGL

Comment: Don't see any /LIBPATH:xxx options, maybe you have to set one for OpenGL

Comment: yes, it looks like that, but should be this not linked via existing project files?

Comment: It should, and apparently it compiles so you have GL/gl.h somewhere, so I would guess you have libs on your system but path is wrong. Or you might want to look at driver support from you videocard vendor, they do supply advanced OpenGL. Without vendor you're going to get default software renderer which is something like OpenGL 1.1 and EXTREMELY slow